# echo value from the textbox while textbox added dynamically by user

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, textbox

I would like to show the value from textbox that user type in after the user click on submit.

In the page, I add one button "ADD TEXTBOX" which make the user can add the textbox by themselves for the maximum 10 textboxes.

Here is my current code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 2;

  $("#addButton").click(function() {

    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' + '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 2) {
      alert("System required at least one.");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
  <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
      <label>Textbox #1 :</label>
      <input type='textbox' id='textbox1' name="textbox1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
  <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Now, I would like to show all the value from the textbox when the user click on the submit button by using php.

This for loop does not show anything after I clicked submit

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        for($i = 1; $i< 10; $i++)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['textbox'+$i]))
            {
                $obj = $_POST['textbox'+$i];

                echo $obj;
            }
        }
   }
?>
```

Is there a way to let php check whether the textbox exist or check how many textbox exist in the current form?

Comment: any error or not working

Comment: The connector in PHP isn't `+` like in JS or Java, use a simple dot `.` instead.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks man, it works. I just know about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check with php if textbox exists use :

```
if(isset($_POST['textboxn']))
{

}
```

You can also check every textbox in one loop

```
for($i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
    if(isset($_POST['textbox'+i]))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is good and I will just add that if you want to save some exec time you can pass the values as an array changing the names to "whatever[]" and after having retrieved it from $_POST iterate it.

Comment: Anyway with just 10 textboxes this probably won't make a big difference

Comment: I tried to use the for loop option, but after I click on submit button, it does not show anything. I've update my php code

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with following form tag

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
```

For iterating text boxes use for loop

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['textbox'+$i]))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the action value in the form tag.